# Three.js camera rotation defying the laws of mathematics

Tags: 3d, coffeescript, three.js

In my application I display a 3D figure, and present the user with controls to rotate their view of the object. Instead of actually rotating the object, my preference goes out to rotate the camera *around* the object, so that adding actions like zooming in later is a bit more straightforward.

Rotating a camera in a circle with some radius seems like an easy job with Three.js. Simply reposition and re-aim the camera around each point of a circle with some radius in the XZ-plane. My code does this in the following way:

```
render: ->
    @camera.lookAt @model.position
    @renderer.render @scene, @camera

rotate: (theta)->
    @rotation += theta

    @camera.position.x = @cameraDistance * Math.sin(@rotation)
    @camera.position.z = @cameraDistance * Math.cos(@rotation)

    @.render()
```

The `rotate()` method is called whenever the user clicks a button.

This seems straightforward and is in fact basically what is being used in many Three.js example applications. The motion the figure makes isn't stationary rotation when I do this however - it does rotate but seems to move around in some elliptical fashion as well (see screenshots).

Furthermore, when doing my sanity checks I found out that executing `console.log square(@camera.position.x) + console.log square(@camera.position.z)` does not yield the `@cameraDistance` figure, but rather values that grow from something very tiny to huge values. It seems that the unit circle identity does not hold for me in this case, for some reason.

It feels like I'm missing something obvious here. Can anybody tell me what it is?

[image: Neutral position]
[image: Figure is not stationary]
[image: Moves out of the picture]
[image: Passes in front of the camera]

Comment: Let's try the obvious first just to find out what the situation is. Is the figure at 0, 0, 0? Is theta in Radians? Are the resulting values greater than @cameraDistance or less that -@cameraDistance?

Comment: Oh. I can't remember the coordinate system for three.js, but the code you put up there `@camera.position.z` sets the `z` value, but in your other statement you're looking at `@camera.position.y`. Is `z` up-down, or in-out?

Comment: Yes, they both are. Even if they would not be, the circle equation would still have to hold, because it is independent of the position of the figure. I'm assuming the circle equation failing and the figure's odd rotation are related, of course, which might not be the case.

Comment: Z here is supposed back-to-front, and X here is left-to-right. I don't set the Y-value because I don't want the camera to move up or down. The motion the object describes at least is in the plane I desire (the XZ plane) so that seems to be alright as far as that goes.

Comment: Yeah but my point is that when you're doing the console.log, you're not modifying the `y`, so `square(@camera.position.x) + square(@camera.position.y)` wouldn't equal `@cameraDistance` would it? And more importantly, you need a square root there.

Comment: Ah right, that was a typo. The equation that should hold here is that for every `t`, `r sin^2 t + r cos^2 t = r`, and at the moment it doesn't.

Comment: Okay, well create a jsfiddle with your actual code so we can get a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: Whoops, the equation should read r^2 sin^2 t + r^2 cos^2 t = r^2. Should still be a constant though.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question:

I'm pretty sure you just mixed up sin and cos.

OP's code:

```
@camera.position.x = @cameraDistance * Math.sin(@rotation)
@camera.position.z = @cameraDistance * Math.cos(@rotation)
```

Correct code:

```
@camera.position.x = @cameraDistance * Math.cos(@rotation)
@camera.position.z = @cameraDistance * Math.sin(@rotation)
```

Comment: I don't actually have access to the code anymore, but would this not simply cause a different rotation? And the unit circle problem should still hold as well.